# Public virtual method overridden as protected in inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a protected abstract virtual method `myMethod()` defined in class C. Class D inherits from C and defines `myMethod()`. Now class E also inherits from C and also defines `myMethod()`. So I have something like this:

This looks like this

```
class C
{
protected:
    virtual void myMethod() = 0;
}

class D : public class C
{
protected:
    void myMethod() {/*Do something*/};

    void anotherMethod();
}

class E : public class C
{
protected:
    void myMethod() {/*Do something else*/};
}
```

Now if in `D::anotherMethod()` I have a pointer to an object of class E then I cannot call `E::myMethod()`. Nothing wrong here: D and E have different hierarchies hence I cannot call `E::myMethod()` from D. i.e the below code does not compile which is expected:

```
void D::anotherMethod()
{
    E* myE = new E();

    myE->myMethod();
}
```

Now if I change the declaration of C and make `E::myMethod()` public (while keeping the overridden method in D and E `protected`), such as in the code below, it compiles:

```
class C
{
public:
    virtual void myMethod() = 0;
}

class D : public class C
{
protected:
    void myMethod() {/*Do something*/};

    void anotherMethod();
}

class E : public class C
{
protected:
    void myMethod() {/*Do something else*/};
}
```

I only changed `public` to `protected` inside C, not in the inherited classes D and E.

Does anyone know why it compiles and what is the logic behind it?

Thanks!

Antoine.

Comment: I think, your design is bad. Why do you need to hide a method, which is declared as public by your interface? Also if D is derived from C, than D is C, as well as E is C. Why should D contain E?

Comment: Hello dousin, this is a hierarchy, D is a branch and E is a leaf: branches can contain leaves... As for the "bad design", you may be right and I may need to reconsider my architecture or not. But first I would like to know more about the unexpected behavior I observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `C` interface as it is public:
`E` interface is protected and `D` can't access from `E` but can from base class `C`

As follow:

```
class C
{
public:
    virtual void myMethod() = 0;
};

class E : public C
{
protected:
    void myMethod() {/*Do something else*/};
};


class D : public C
{
protected:
    void myMethod() {/*Do something*/};

    void anotherMethod(){
        //C* myE = new E(); // does compile
        E* myE = new E(); // doesn't compile

        myE->myMethod();
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello Jarod42, not sure whether this is compiler specific but the code  you mention does compile with my MSVC 2008...

Comment: So it should be a bug/extension of msvc, I think.